# Weierstrass factorisation

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am looking for an example, and I am wondering if there exists $F(z)$ entire such that
$$
F(z)=\prod \left(1-\frac{z}{z_n}\right) 
$$
where $z_n \in \mathbb{C}^-$ and $|F(z)|< C$ when $0 \leq \Im(z)\leq K$ fixed.

Thanks

Comment: $\sin(z)/z\phantom{}$

Comment: no zeros in $C^-$

Comment: Huh? If $f(z)=\sin(z)/z$ then $f$ has infinitely many zeroes.

Comment: You are right, but the zeros have to be in the lower half complex plane.

Comment: However I think that $ sin(z+i)$ could be a counterexample.

Comment: Oh - the ${}^-$ was invisible in $z_n\in\Bbb C^-$.